# Запуск функции только при окончании программы [Rust]

Tags: rust

В начале программа запускает сервера Redis. Через `std::process::Command`.

Во время работы программа может экстренно завершится (`panic!` и т.д.).

И конечно же, Redis не отключается, а продолжает работать. Хотелось бы сделать такую функцию, которая будет работать при завершении программы, где я буду останавливать все сторонни проги и т.д.

Программа клиентская, то есть должна работать как одна `exe`-шка.
Можно конечно это все обернуть как 2-ая exe-шка внутри другой, и просто ждать завершения, но хотелось бы более нативное решение.

Comment: Предположу, что можно запускать один и тот же exe-файл в двух разных режимах, например передав нужный режим с помощью аргумента командной строки (первый процесс запускает Redis и потом запускает свой собственный exe-файл в другом режиме, а второй процесс уже занимается нужной работой и находится под контролем первого процесса)

Comment: оставлю [ссылку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57860613/how-to-add-a-shutdown-hook-to-a-rust-program) на enSO…

Comment: попробуйте `std::panic::set_hook` - но это сработает не во все случаях. Там бывают такие падения, когда уже ничего не выполняется.

Comment: @chabapok спасибо. Заметил пока что не срабатывает когда возвращаешь `Error` из `main`, но пока достаточно.